# Balance too low

Tags: blockexplorer

I used SimpleSwap.io to exchange my USDC and convert them to XTZ. SimpleSwap indicates that they sent everything to my address: (tz1eGFbAty8LpqRQab9FQ53aMFmy2bFbC5PG) without error but when I check my balance it indicates $ 0 that they never reached my address in Binance. So I started investigating using: https://tezblock.io where I get msj: transaction Failed and followed by the following message: Balance too low The operation tried to spend 134.925507 XTZ while the account only has 116.498499 XTZ. Does this mean that I lost this money, or do I have a way to get it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the [operation here](https://tzkt.io/op91Qi5wPX96nueif6FVhGn1vRn4YvzbxMaWX9zrTNy4u8MUs5j/3787771) and it indicates that this account only had XTZ 116 while they tried to send you XTZ 134. The link proves the transfer didn't go through, you should probably contact them and ask them to send the transaction again :)

Comment: The SimpleSwap team help me. Thanks for your help.